# Optimizing Dictionary.TryGetValue()

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

I'm coding an computationally expensive application (NLP machine learning task) which is in a need of optimization.

Since my code has a lot of for-loops, I've used the `Parallel.For` (and variants) to parallelize the outer-most loops.
I've also used arrays and `Dictionary`s to build a few indices which cut the cost considerably.

VS2010's profiler indicated that the application spends most of it's time in `Dictionary.TryGetValue()` (which is a side-product of indices).

This begs the question whether I can do better? And how?

My first question is whether there is general consensus that `ConcurrentDictionary.TryGetValue` performs any better than
`Dictionary.TryGetValue` in my scenario -- many readers, no writers?

I'm not motivated to code my own hashmap as it will probably fare worse than .NET's collections. But are there any libraries out there that guarantee faster lookups for my scenario?

Perhaps the hashcode implementation is slowing things down?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Dictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) is already very well optimized, according to MSDN:

> This method approaches an O(1) operation.

You haven't mentioned what are the keys of your dictionary, if you use a custom type, make sure you've implemented its [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) method properly, as dictionaries and hash tables rely on it and use it extensively.

Comment: `O(1)` is not quite the same thing as "very well optimized". I could add `Thread.Sleep(60000)` to the start of a method and still legitimately claim it was `O(1)` ;p

Comment: Yes, you can, but if you are after maximum performance you won't ;) What I mean, is that the **TryGetValue** method is unlikely to be causing slow downs, but the **GetHashCode** method may be doing so if not coded properly.

Comment: I've profiled the GetHashCode method, and the program spends less than 0,1% time in it. I guess I'll need to approach this bottleneck in a different way.

Answer (score 4):

> My first question is whether there is general consensus that `ConcurrentDictionary.TryGetValue` performs any better than `Dictionary.TryGetValue` in my scenario -- many readers, no writers?

I haven't tested it, but I would typically *expect* a concurrent implementation to have additional overheads, being slightly *slower* overall. The difference comes when you need to synchronize access - i.e. if your read-centric code needs to `lock` the dictionary, then the concurrent version (without locks) may be faster. Since you mention that your code has no writers, I'm guessing you aren't using `lock`s, and thus there won't be any reason to look at one implementation over the other. That said, it may be worth *profiling* it, but even if it *was* faster (and again: I expect it to be slightly *slower*), I would only expect it to be *slightly* faster - so unlikely to change the performance significantly.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at profiler result which claims a method is accountable for most of the execution time, it is also important to figure out if it is because:

1. The method has been called too many times, or
2. a single invocation of the method takes a long time

If TryGetValue accounts for the most of the time because it is called too many times, it probably is an indication that you need to reduce the **complexity** of your indexing/lookup algorithm so that TryGetValue can be called less frequently.

It will only be worthy to further investigate the `TryGetValue` method if it takes a long time **per invocation**. However as Pavel mentioned, `TryGetValue` **itself** is already well optimized. It is very likely the method(s) invoked by `TryGetValue`, the method(s) that can be overridden by you, is to be blamed. Typically you need to pay attention to `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method. Both of them will be invoked when calling `TryGetValue`. `Equals` may be invoked more than once. My experience is that `Equals` method usually has a better chance to be the problem since the built-in equality comparison of certain framework construct involves reflection.